# Get StringRelatedField along with PrimaryKeyRelatedField using Serializer in DRF

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Sorry for this newbie question, but I simply cannot find my way reading the manual.

models

```
    #Subject
class TemaPai(models.Model):
    subject = models.TextField()
    disciplines = models.ManyToManyField(Materia)

    # order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "temas-pais (subjects)"


# Order and junction
class TemaPaiOrdem(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(TemaPai, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Materia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        var2 = self.subject.subject
        var = self.discipline.discipline
        return var2 + ' - ' + var

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Temas-pais-ordem"
        unique_together = ('subject', 'discipline')
```

serializers

```
class TemaPaiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    disciplines = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Materia.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = TemaPai
        fields = ('id', 'subject', 'url', 'disciplines')


class TemaPaiOrdemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    discipline = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Materia.objects.all())
    subject = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=TemaPai.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = TemaPaiOrdem
        fields = ('id', 'subject','discipline', 'order')
```

Well, TemaPaiOrdemSerializer is giving me a list like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": 1,
        "discipline": 1,
        "order": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subject": 2,
        "discipline": 1,
        "order": 11
    }
]
```

It is fine. But I want to retrieve the subject string representation (from TemaPai model) as well, as a read_only field. So my desired list would be something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": 1,
        "subject_name": "Introduction",
        "discipline": 1,
        "order": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subject": 2,
        "subject_name": "Advanced stuff",
        "discipline": 1,
        "order": 11
    }
]
```

I am trying to use

```
subject_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source:'subject')
```

with no success. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ,

```
subject_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='subject',read_only=True)
```

hence your serializer will be like,

```
class TemaPaiOrdemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    discipline = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Materia.objects.all())
    subject = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=TemaPai.objects.all())
    subject_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='subject',read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TemaPaiOrdem
        fields = ('id', 'subject', 'subject_name', 'discipline', 'order')
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I didn't know I could just use `source=` with `StringRelatedField`. Thanks, buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` in `source` argument for lookup related model's field like this:

```
subject_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='subject.subject')
```

Comment: @LuisRock yep, it was my mistake. You can use `.`. But Jerin's answer looks cleaner.

Comment: I kept trying to use `source="subject__subject"`, but the `.` worked for me.  I wonder why DRF didn't use double underscores like the rest of Django.